How to tell if a parameterization covers all integer solutions (particularly for $x^2 + y^n = z^2$)
Something I have been confused on for a while is how to tell if a parameterization is complete. For the sake of clarity, I define complete as giving all solutions of the desired type.
In particular, I want to find out if the following parameterization of $x^2 + y^n = z^2$ gives all integer solutions:
$(x,y,z)$ = ($k^n(2(p-s))^{n-2} - (p-s)^2,2k(p-s),k^n(2(p-s))^{n-2} + (p-s)^2$)
I got this solution from individ here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1052831
Any help would be greatly appreciated

It helps if you have access to a derivation of the parametrization. If the derivation begins, "Assume such-and-such an equation holds. Then it must be the case that ....", then, provided the argument is correct, the parametrization is complete. Now, your example asks for $y^n$ to be a difference of two squares, and all expressions of a given $N$ as a difference of two squares can be simply described, in terms of the divisors of $N$.

@GerryMyerson Unfortunately- I do not- I just have the link from artofproblemsolving.com

OK, but, in this case, following the points I made about that equation, it shouldn't be hard to determine whether that's a complete parametrization.

I am very much a layman when it comes to mathematics. I know the difference of squares would be $(c+a)(c-a)$ and so $c+a = (q^n)(p_1^{n-u_1})(p_2^{n-u_2})...$ and $c - a = (s^n)(p_1^{u_1})(p_2^{u_2})...$ then we can solve for c and a, but I'm not sure how that gets me a complete parameterization for any n? Unless that's it, which would work technically.

That's basically it. If $N=rs$ with $r\le s$ both even or both odd, then $N=x^2-y^2$ with $x=(r+s)/2$ and $y=(r-s)/2$, and all expressions of $N$ has a difference of two squares arise this way.

I suggest you figure out how to  program a partial search for your question. That is what I did with your previous question
